# Symfony2 not loading Service

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, symfony-2.7

im trying to create/load a service with Synfony 2 following the documentation book example, but i encounter this problem. Currenty i have

```
<?php
//src/AppBundle/Services/AmazonWS.php
namespace AppBundle\Services;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
class AmazonWS
{

    function __construct($bucket,$key,$secret){}
}
```

and at my services.yml:

```
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value
  amazonws.S3_BUCKET : "synfony"
  amazonws.S3_KEY : "my_key"
  amazonws.S3_SECRET : "my_secret"

services:
#    service_name:
#        class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
#        arguments: ["@another_service_name", "plain_value", "%parameter_name%"]

AmazonWS:
  class: AppBundle\Services\AmazonWS
  arguments: ["%amazonws.S3_BUCKET%","%amazonws.S3_KEY%","%amazonws.S3_SECRET%"]
```

and im getting the following errors:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                                                                                                                  
  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "AmazonWS" (in /home/sergio/Desktop/hello_symfony_heroku/app/config/services.yml). Looked for namespace "AmazonWS", found "framewor  
  k", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "debug", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution" in /home/sergio/Desktop/hello_symfony_hero  
  ku/app/config/services.yml (which is being imported from "/home/sergio/Desktop/hello_symfony_heroku/app/config/config.yml").                                                                  


  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                    
  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "AmazonWS" (in /home/sergio/Desktop/hello_symfony_heroku/app/config/services.yml). Looked for namespace "AmazonWS", found "framewor  
  k", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "debug", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"
```

I got config.yml with the

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
```

Comment: Try to add indent before AmazonWS in services.yml

Comment: Do you have a DependencyInjection folder in charge to load the services.yml file ?

Comment: No, Just Brand new project with the additions above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use the Dependency injection from your AppBundle?

`src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
        );
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

And then use your services.yml that is located in `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` (create it if it doesn't exsist).

Comment: Thank you, i skipped the bundle chapter, thought i could Just declare the service, thank you once more

Answer (score 1):

Indent:

```
services:
    AmazonWS:
        class: AppBundle\Services\AmazonWS
        arguments: ["%amazonws.S3_BUCKET%","%amazonws.S3_KEY%","%amazonws.S3_SECRET%"]
```